# What is the database best practice for schema & users for microservices

Tags: sql, oracle, microservices

I want to create an Oracle database for microservice.  Should I stick to standard XXX_OWNER and XXX_USER or switch to a simpler single-user that owns schema and uses it?

In monolithic applications database tend to be common for several applications. It necessitate two users and its a best practice for monolithic applications. XXX_OWNER owns the schema and all objects are created in it. XXX_USER is used by the application and has access to the objects created inside SCHEMA_OWNER's schema.  However, this is heavy handed approach in microservices world where each microservice has its own schema and it's locked down to only that service.  Are there any drawbacks to ditch the 2-user strategy and move to a single user strategy in case of microservices.

Old Approach

```
CREATE USER SCHEMA_OWNER identified by xxx;

CREATE USER APP_USER identified by xxx;

CREATE TABLE XXX_TEST (ABC VARCHAR(50 BYTE) PRIMARY KEY);

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DATE on XXX_TEST TO APP_USER;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM XXX_TEST FOR SCHEMA_OWNER.XXX_TEST
```

New Approach

```
CREATE USER APP_USER identified by xxx;

CREATE TABLE XXX_TEST (ABC VARCHAR(50 BYTE) PRIMARY KEY);
```

The single-user seems to be simpler to develop, deploy and operate.  However, there is a concern within the team about moving away from the age-old best practice of two-user practice.  What would be a better approach in the microservice world for databases?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with microservices. This would appear to be about user management in oracle.

Comment: In monolithic applications database tend to be common for several applications.  It necessitate an owner account who own the objects and several application users having access to those objects.  However, this is heavy handed approach in microservices.  Should we rethink our database user management for microservices?

Comment: OK that is a bit clearer. Please update the question with this information. I don't personally know enough about Oracle to answer your question, but I do know about microservices. And you are correct, usually each service has it's own database and should probably not have any shared database infrastructure, like the same owner.

Comment: I guess when you consider breaking best practise you should understand why something is considered best practise. In my experience you can move away from best practise only when you have this understanding, and you can articulate why best practise no longer applies to your situation.

Comment: Microservices architecture often requires that best practises should not be followed, for example, duplication of data across multiple services is encouraged, even though it breaks best practises.

Comment: tom, I have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Not much overhead in Oracle by having two users per microservice, and the enhanced security is far worth it.

Comment: @MarkStewart, the overhead is mainly around efforts and complexity.  As you can see above creating a table requires 3 statements in 2-users and just a single statement from 1-user approach.  Please list main security benefits.

Comment: Security / Maintainability: see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=separating-code-from-data